# LWC Component CloseActionScreenEvent not working

Tags: lightning-web-components

We are developing LWC component and we are trying to close screen using following action.

(Alerts works in desktop mode but not in ios or androird)

```
import { CloseActionScreenEvent } from 'lightning/actions';
```

this is added as import too

```
handleClose(){
    alert('**handleClose*' );
    this.dispatchEvent(new CloseActionScreenEvent());
    //this.dispatchEvent(new CloseActionScreenEvent({ bubbles: true, composed: true }));
    alert('**handleClose After*' );
}
```

Comment: lwc quick action not supported for salesforce Mobile ``https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/use-config-for-quick-actions.html`

Comment: I am unable to get this to work even on desktop browsers. Keep getting a  error " [EventTarget.dispatchEvent: Argument 1 does not implement interface Event.]"